# What is the difference between GFP and rhodopsin?

Tags: biochemistry, light

GFP and Rhodopsin are both fluorescent proteins. What is the main difference between GFP and Rhodopsin in terms of how they work? I know that their excitation and emission wavelengths are different, but in terms of the biological mechanism, how are they different?

Comment: Rhodopsins are photo-signal receptors. GFP does not function as a receptor.

Comment: @RoniSaiba so do you mean to say that rhodopsins carry out a subsequent biological function upon being exposed to light, whereas GFP does not have this subsequent function?